# How to pronounce (OS X) Yosemite in Australian English

Tags: pronunciation, australian-english, spelling-pronunciations

In Australian English, is (OS X) Yosemite pronounced to rhyme with "vegemite", or the same as in [Yosemite Sam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosemite_Sam), who is named after the national park?

Comment: Say your prayers varmint! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite /joʊˈsɛmɨtiː/ yoh-sem-it-ee (I don't think it matters what dialect you speak it in - it's a trademark or whatever - so Apple call the shots)

Comment: I'm with Frank. Have there ever been products from Apple (or any manufacturer for that matter) whose name was supposed to be pronounced differently in different parts of the world?

Comment: Most global products are produced with anodyne or coined names which can't be mispronounced. That said, Toyota's MR2 was renamed in France.

Comment: ... and Vauxhall Motors had trouble marketing the Nova in Spain ...

Comment: @DavidGarner That is an urban legend which has was not rooted in reality.

Comment: Sorry, Mr Lister.  Is that also true about Rolls Royce and their Silver Mist, do you know?

Comment: @MrLister - Pretty sure that AMC had trouble with the Matador in Spanish-speaking countries.

Comment: The only way to actually answer this question is to poll a number of Australians.

Answer (score 8):

The operating system is ultimately named after the valley, just like the national park, and Sam. The valley, in turn, is named after the [Central Miwok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miwok) name for the [Ahwahneechee people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahwahnechee_people), *yoṣṣe’meti* ‘the killers’ (apparently from the root *yoṣ-* ‘kill’ enlarged by a relativising agentive suffix *-e* ‘one who’ and the plural suffix *-meti*).

The English pronunciation of the name is always any given speaker’s local phonetic realisation of the following phonemic representation:<sup>1</sup>

> /jɵˈsεmɨti/       *yuh-SEM-ət-ee*

This goes whether you’re refers to the people (though they should be called by their endonym, Ahwahneechee or just Ahwahnee), the valley, the national park, the Sam, or the operating system. The word *Yosemite* is never, to my knowledge, in any circumstance supposed to rhyme with *vegemite* (rhyme /-aɪt/).

There’s a good page about the origin of the name on the park’s website, [Yosemite online](http://www.yosemite.ca.us/library/origin_of_word_yosemite.html).

(Of course, as Frank mentions in his comment, *OS X Yosemite* is a trademark by Apple, and Apple are free to prescribe any pronunciation they wish for it. Happily, they’ve chosen to prescribe the only pronunciation the word otherwise has.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I’m using Wikipedia’s guidelines for a uniform way to represent English phonemes in [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English) and [pronunciation respelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Pronunciation_respelling_key). Note especially that /ɵ/, /ɨ/, and /i/ are *variable vowels*: they are pronounced differently by different speakers, even within the same dialect—a kind of ‘abstract phonemes’:

- /ɵ/ is realised as either /o/ or /ə/ (in American English usually pronounced [oʊ] and [ə])
- /ɨ/ is really just an allophone of /ə/ that can be realised as either [ə] (as in the indefinite article *an*) or [ɪ/ɨ] (a reduced form of the vowel in *hit*)
- /i/ is also known as the *happy* vowel; it can be any of [ɪ, i, iː]

So the single phonemic representation /jɵˈsεmɨti/ covers 12 different basic possibilities. In standard Broadcast American: [jəˈsεməɾɪ], [jəˈsεməɾi], [jəˈsεməɾiː]; [jəˈsεmɨɾɪ], [jəˈsεmɨɾi], [jəˈsεmɨɾiː]; [joʊˈsεməɾɪ], **[joʊˈsεməɾi]**, [joʊˈsεməɾiː]; [joʊˈsεmɨɾɪ], **[joʊˈsεmɨɾi]**, [joʊˈsεmɨɾiː]. I would say the bolded ones are the most common. Other dialects, of course, may realise both the vowels and the /t/ differently.

Comment: What?  You mean "Vegemite" isn't pronounced "veg-em-uh-tee"???

Comment: @HotLicks Only if you’re one of those people who also rhymes _vegetable_ with _detestable_. ;-)

Comment: Your pronunciation doesn't match what [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosemite_National_Park): /joʊˈsɛmɨtiː/ yoh-SEM-it-ee

Comment: @curiousdannii It does actually. Wikipedia just (annoyingly) doesn’t distinguish /phonemic writing/ from [phonetic writing], and in this particular case, the article kind of mixes them up, even. I wrote the pronunciation in strictly phonemic terms, since the phonetic realisation varies a lot from speaker to speaker. The vowel [ɨ] is a surface phone of the phoneme /ə/ that may or may not be present in this word; it is not a separate phoneme. [ε], [oʊ], and [iː] are common (AmE) surface phones of /e/, /o/, and /i/. So in Broadcast American, /joˈseməti/ = [joʊˈsεməɾi(ː)] or [joʊˈsεmɨɾi(ː)].

Comment: (The fact that the Wikipedia pronunciation has [t] in what is otherwise phonetic notation is where it gets mixed up—very few Americans would pronounce the /t/ as an actual [t] in this word: nearly everyone would reduce it to a flap [ɾ]. I’ll edit the non-IPA forms a bit to match Wikipedia’s version better. I’ve never been any good with the whole pronunciation respelling thing.)

Comment: Having had a closer look at Wikipedia’s _IPA for English_ guide, their transcription is more phonemic and not as inconsistent as I thought (though it is less standard IPA). I’ve adapted to their style added a note to explain how it works. The only difference now is that the Wikipedia page incorrectly (until I edit it in a minute) has /iː/ instead of /i/ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how it's meant to be pronounced, I suspect most Aussies probably would pronounce it so that it rhymes with Vegemite. If you haven't heard words pronounced before you follow the normal pronunciation patterns.

Comment: And would you condone Americans saying *Brissbain*?

Comment: @Peter Shor The French say and write _Londres_, and the entente cordiale is still around. Mind you, _Paris_ sounds different in the UK from how some think it should be pronounced. It seems that it's Arkansas and Kansas where they get exercised.

Comment: I suspect most Aussies are familiar enough with the word "Yosemite" that "jɵˈsεmɨti" *is* the normal pronunciation pattern.

Comment: @Edwin: the French are speaking French; when they speak English, they generally say *"London"*.

Comment: @Peter You're asserting that Strine is English?